# What is the difference between different classes of AC Compressors?

Tags: ac, mercedes-benz, e55

I am replacing the compressor in a Mercedes W211 E55 AMG. The original part had a solenoid without an integrated diode, but the matched replacement did, so it is incompatible and would not start, because the control circuit in the car includes the diode already.

The original was of type 7SEU17C. I am looking at a few other replacement options, and judging by photos, a few models of type 7SEU16C seem like they would will work, specifically a Nissens 890634.

Does anyone know what other differences between these types would be? Externally they appear identical regarding mounting points and the pulley. I see a difference in oil capacity, but is that just a matter of internal design, or does it relate to performance and the ability to keep up with the refrigerant capacity of the overall system?

Thank you!

**Update**

I purchased the Nissens 890634, it was pictured as having a ECV without the diode, but arrived with a sticker indicating diode + CS Valve. I can't find a reliable source for a compatible compressor, so the only option remaining to me is to piece together a working one with separately-sourced correct valve, pulley, and the actual body.

Denso diagram:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I should've been here long ago, I'm active in StackOverflow and car forums, been repairing and upgrading my personal MBs for 15 years.